# Rotationally invariant function in three-sphere

Tags: rotations, spherical-harmonics

I know that every rotationally invariant function $f(x,y,z)$ in two-sphere $S^2$ must satisfy 
\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z)=f(h(\theta)(x,y,z)^T)
\end{align*}
for all $\theta$ and $x,y,z$, where 
\begin{align*}
h(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta &-\sin\theta\ &0\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Here the rotation is assumed to be around $z$-axis.

What I am still confused about is, how to generalize this in case of three-sphere $S^3$? I know that we can somehow use the fact that $S^3$ is a group of unit quaternions but I do not know where to start. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of rotationally invariant function? The statement to be proved is almost what I would call the definition of rotational invariance about the $z$-axis.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't addressed the question in a good way. What I am asking is, how can I produce such matrix $A$ such that if $\textbf{x} = (x,y,z,w)^T$ then $f(\textbf{x})=f(A\textbf{x})$ for all $x,y,z,w$? Such matrix $A$ must be $4 \times 4$. @Travis

Comment: Assuming you want to fix, analogously, the $w$-axis, we can just take $A$ to have the form $\pmatrix{B & 0 \\ 0 & \pm 1}$, where $B$ is an orthogonal $3 \times 3$ matrix. Such matrices have a reasonable parameterization.